# Builder with constructor or factory method?

Tags: java, factory-method, builder-pattern

Let's say I have a class `Dot` with a builder:

```java
public class Dot {
    private final Double x;
    private final Double y;
    private final Color color;

    private Dot(Double x, Double y, Color color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public static Builder createBuilder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public Double getX() { return x; }

    public Double getY() { return y; }

    public Color getColor() { return color; }

    public Builder getBuilder() {
        return new Builder().setX(x).setY(y).setColor(color);
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private Double x;
        private Double y;
        private Color color;

        public Builder setX(Double x) {
            this.x = x;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setY(Double y) {
            this.y = y;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
            return this;
        }

        public Dot build() {
            return new Dot(x, y, color);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I see two possible ways one could instantiate the builder. Through its constructor:

```java
new Dot.Builder().setX(...
```

or through a factory method:

```java
Dot.createBuilder().setX(...
```

(In the latter case I would make the `Builder`'s constructor `private`.)

Factory methods (or factories) are (to my knowledge) useful when the actual type of the returned value might change later on. This is something that is probably not going to occur with a builder.

My best argument for using a factory method would be: Say that the builder uses a final field `String id` that has to be set in its constructor, but certain restrictions apply to what constitutes an ID. Throwing an exception on an illegal id string [should not be done in a constructor](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/OBJ11-J.+Be+wary+of+letting+constructors+throw+exceptions). Therefore a factory method would be better.

However I feel like I missed some more important arguments. Does a best practice for this case exist? What other arguments exist for/against using a factory method here?

Comment: Despite what your link says, throwing exceptions in constructors is very good style. It's the easiest way to write robust code as every object is responsible for its own correctness. The link merely states that an object can still exist after constructor validation failed, which makes ctor validation *unsuitable for security checks* if you run untrusted code in the same JVM where the attacker can extend your class. Under all other circumstances, exceptions in constructors are great.

Comment: What's the use case for introducing a builder or a factory instead of directly using the Dot(x,y,color) constructor? Create some new Dot? Create a copy? Create a moved or differently-colored copy? Or is "Dot" just a simplified example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Builder` is a class internal to `Dot`.  For me this tells me that `Builder` is strongly coupled with `Dot` and that `Builder` is a utility of `Dot` for some objective, in this case object construction.

This is objectively one step away from `Builder` being an internal class hidden away from the caller entirely.  The only link you, the caller, should have to `Builder` *should be through* `Dot` as a general rule.  And although there's nothing stopping you from making `Builder`'s constructor public and accessing it directly, I confirmly believe it is an antipattern.

Therefore, you should have a static factory method in `Dot` that returns an instance of `Builder`.  You mention that it isn't likely that you'd ever need to extend `Builder`, and that's all fine and good, but when you're given a more flexible option with no drawbacks while you're developing, you grab hold of it like your life depended on it.  Should you ever need to extend `Builder`, you could make `Builder<T>` an interface and create a customized `DotBuilder<Dot>` which implements it which when called creates an instance of `Dot`.

> My best argument for using a factory method would be: Say that the
>   builder uses a final field String id that has to be set in its
>   constructor, but certain restrictions apply to what constitutes an ID.
>   Throwing an exception on an illegal id string should not be done in a
>   constructor. Therefore a factory method would be better.

I'm usually against constructors performing work that might likely throw exceptions.  It's one thing to throw an exception in a constructor for an invalid parameter or for a very unlikely situation such as Xml implementation not existing, and quite another to attempt to establish a database connection which can and will fail quite easily.  If you did need to do work in your `Builder` constructor, you could do so lazily putting it off until the actual creation of the object as to not make your constructor explode.  Though if I've got `Builder` class pegged correctly, it isn't the type of class that *should* ever explode upon creation.  If that isn't your case, give serious thought to making it work in the way that one might expect it to work (aka  possible exceptions when calling `build()` method only).

Also if I may add, having a builder class `Builder` with many of the same methods as `Dot` is not probably a good idea.  Your situation may be different and this may be the simplified version, so if this doesn't apply to you, ignore this advice.  Though it is my opinion that `Builder` is largely unnecessary here.  `Dot` can return `this` after each setter and perform precisely the same functionality.  Give it some thought.

Comment: In OP's design, the Dot class is immutable. Adding setters to make it mutable would drastically change the design. Under such circumstances a builder does have value. Regarding validation: performing validation *before* a (private) ctor is called can be sensible. But wouldn't lazy validation after the ctor make the system terribly unpredictable? I've had to use that strategy once on a larger scale and it was a total pain due to convoluted data flows. Btw I don't think asserting object invariants violates the point of the “no behaviour in constructors” guideline.

Comment: @amom When I say "throw an exception in a constructor for an invalid parameter", I mean to say parameter validation in general.  I don't think anything is wrong with making sure the parameters are proper.  Though there should be nothing of the sort for `Builder` since it doesn't have parameters in this case.  Also, it's true, Dot is immutable, and that's certainly advantageous.  It depends on his design, but I would argue that it is a little excessive for a simple bean class with no business logic.